# Show only discontinuous points in Highcharts line graph

Tags: highcharts

I am using a Highcharts line graph to show data that is sometimes discontinuous.  I have markers turned off because that was the display preference of our design team.  Isolated data points disappear, though, and are visible only on hover.

Is there a way to turn markers on, but only for isolated data points? (i.e. I do NOT want to set `markers: {enabled: true}`, but I do want the solitary point on the far right of the series to be displayed).

[fiddle with example](https://jsfiddle.net/q8a3rbug/1/) (note the isolated data point on the far right of the series - it is invisible unless you hover over the single point):

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },

    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            marker: {
                enabled: false
            }
        }
    },

    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, NaN, 54.4]
    }]
});
```

default:

[image]

on hover:
[image]

EDIT:

I tried

```
...
       series: {
           marker: {
               enabled: true,
               radius: 1
           }
       }
...
```

but the lone point is nearly invisible.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can enable markers for individual data points:

```
    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, NaN, {
            y: 54.4,
            marker: {
                enabled: true
            }
        }]
    }]
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/2prxc63m/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.data.marker.enabled

Comment: I only want the data point by itself to be displayed.  I do not want data points covered by the line to be displayed.

Comment: Hi @Brian Witte, So you need to find these kind of points and enable marker for them. Plese check this example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/u5fcpnzb/

Comment: Thank you @ppotaczek That's what I was looking for.